# A chat bot with .NET front end?

Tags: c#, .net, artificial-intelligence, bots

I need an AI Bot for a chat service which can imitate a human. I have tried **ALICE** with **AIMLBot(C#)** as a front-end but it didn't work very well.

Are there any good bots you would recommend?

Comment: Why do you feel it didn't work very well?

Comment: It becomes obvious that it is a bot very quckly.

Comment: So you want a chat bot that can pass the Turing Test?  I'm pretty sure that's still non-trivial, tbh...

Comment: On BBC news it said that some chat bots can successfully present themselves as females.

Comment: That's a bit sexist, isn't it?  Can they not pass as men, too?

Comment: So you want help making a chatbot you can control that can pass off as a woman to people on the internet?

Comment: I have done this using megahal, but it was quite obvious it is a bot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want something that'll pass the [Turing Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_test), to some lesser or greater degree.  That's non-trivial and quite a big subject.  Start with [Google](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=turing+test) and Wikipedia, but I think you need to set your expectations and requirements before you go too much further.

Comment: Actually, I think he's just looking for a pre-existing chatbot to hook up to an IM front-end. I don't think there's any requirement that it pass a Turing Test. I rememember the ICQ client for Linux (LICQ I think it was?) used to have an "auto-reply" feature you could turn on when you were AKF, and on of the choices was to let the other person chatting talk to "alice" (if it was already installed on your machine).

Comment: But he also stated that "doesn't work very well" meant "It becomes obvious that it is a bot very quckly". Hence my point.

Comment: Ah, well that's just a matter of finding a better chatbot! ;) Perhaps ALICE isn't as good as some others. Oh, and in my reference to the ICQ auto-reply earlier, it would use Eliza as the chatbot, not ALICE, but since it was possible to substitute a custom shell script, ANYthing could be used. I thought that's what this guy wanted: a chatbot with an API He could use to connect with a front-end.